# Error 405 with AJAX, Javascript, Node (Body-Parser and CORS), and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, npm, xmlhttprequest

So, I am trying to create a JSON file from buttons, and I am able to retrieve data from JSON files that I created, but I am unable to post to them using XMLHTTPRequest and/or Ajax. I can add to a JSON file using routes using the urls alone, but I wouldn't know how to set up a route for the following code.

(Also, it seems like no matter what I do, I always get a '405 error message - Method Not Allowed.  I have given permission for the site through Google Chrome Settings Security and I have downloaded all of the packages for NPM Cors and Body-Parser.)

What am I doing that keeps getting me the 405 error, and do I need to create a route that would typically be used for a form to add the data?

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require("cors");


// PORT CONNECTION
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`);
});

//PUBLIC FOLDER
app.use(express.static('public'));

// parse application/json
var jsonBP = app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  });

  // POST /api/users gets JSON bodies
app.post('/api/actions', jsonBP, function (req, res) {
    buttons.response
  });

//CORS
app.use(cors());
```

Javascript:

```
  for (i = 0; i < facialExpressions.length; i++) {
    var CreateButton = document.createElement("button");
    var section = "Facial Expressions";
    CreateButton.innerText = facialExpressions[i];
    document.getElementById("facial").appendChild(CreateButton);
    CreateButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var params = JSON.stringify({
        action: this.innerHTML,
        date: Date(),
        section: "Facial Expressions",
        videoID: videoID,
        username: username
      });

      console.log(params);
      
      
    
      xhr.open("post", "./db/actions.json", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      console.log('READYSTATE: ', xhr.readyState);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status ===201){
          let object = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
          console.log(object);
        }
      }

      //Sends Request
      xhr.send(encodeURIComponent(params));
    
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
  </br></br>
<p id="status"></p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="10%">
                <h3>Facial Expressions</h3>
            </td>
            <td width="50%">
                <h3>Video</h3>
            </td>
            <td width="40%">
                <h3>Physical Actions</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="facial"></div>

            </td>
            <td>

                <div id="videoPlayer"></div>
                <div>
                    <button id="start">Start</button>
                </div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <div id="actions"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually realized that I needed to create a route/REST API.  After doing so, I was able to bypass the 405 error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).